apt is trying to update postgresql package while trying to upgrade openssl
$ sudo apt update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [128 kB]
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:3 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu focal-infra-security InRelease [7450 B]
Get:4 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu focal-infra-updates InRelease [7449 B]
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:6 http://repo.percona.com/percona/apt focal InRelease
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [128 kB]
Hit:8 http://repo.percona.com/prel/apt focal InRelease
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [128 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [3692 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1237 kB]
Fetched 5328 kB in 4s (1195 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
360 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

$ sudo apt install --only-upgrade openssl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libicu60 postgresql-client-10 postgresql-client-13 postgresql-doc-10
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
E: Can't find a source to download version '12.11-0ubuntu0.20.04.1' of 'postgresql-12:amd64'

$ apt-cache policy postgresql-12
postgresql-12:
  Installed: 12.11-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Candidate: 12.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Version table:
     12.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 12.11-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     12.2-4 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages

It looks like it is trying to find the package that is currently installed, not the updated one. Why is apt trying to update another package when I am asking to upgrade a completely different package?
How can I fix this problem ?
Update: /var/lib/dpkg/status says:
Package: postgresql-12
Status: hold reinstreq half-configured
Priority: optional
Section: database
Installed-Size: 40088
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 12.11-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
Config-Version: 12.11-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
Provides: postgresql-contrib-12
Depends: locales | locales-all, postgresql-client-12, postgresql-common (>= 182~), ssl-cert, tzdata, debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0, libc6 (>= 2.29), libgcc-s1 (>= 3.0), libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.14+dfsg), libicu66 (>= 66.1-1~), libldap-2.4-2 (>= 2.4.7), libllvm10 (>= 1:9~svn298832-1~), libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1), libpq5 (>= 9.3~), libselinux1 (>= 2.1.12), libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0), libstdc++6 (>= 5.2), libsystemd0, libuuid1 (>= 2.16), libxml2 (>= 2.7.4), libxslt1.1 (>= 1.1.25), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
Recommends: sysstat
Description: object-relational SQL database, version 12 server
 PostgreSQL is a powerful, open source object-relational database
 system. It is fully ACID compliant, has full support for foreign
 keys, joins, views, triggers, and stored procedures (in multiple
 languages). It includes most SQL:2008 data types, including INTEGER,
 NUMERIC, BOOLEAN, CHAR, VARCHAR, DATE, INTERVAL, and TIMESTAMP. It
 also supports storage of binary large objects, including pictures,
 sounds, or video. It has native programming interfaces for C/C++,
 Java, .Net, Perl, Python, Ruby, Tcl, ODBC, among others, and
 exceptional documentation.

If I run sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq, will it mess up my postgresql instance that is on the machine ?
